# Including StyleSheets in DotNetNuke 8 MVC Modules

Tags: dotnetnuke

How can I include JavaScript like Angular.js or any other JavaScript file in DNN 8 MVC module.

I am new to DNN but I had work experience on ASP.NET MVC.

Can you guide me through how to add JavaScript into my view (.cshtml) file.

I have seen that in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89zxuyj05RA) video have used `ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript` method but 1st argument is `System.Web.UI.Page`. What should I pass as this parameter?

Other way is to use `JAVASCRIPT TOKEN` which I can see with [this](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155247/module-development-in-dnn-8-5--new-tokens-to-support-building-pure-spa-modules) link but its not working as expectd in MVC module nor I am able to find any example to use it with MVC DNN 8 module.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: This is a bit to broad. Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have tried so far. Please, be so kind and reformat the text. It's realy hard to read when everything is put into one line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a module project template like Chris Hammond's, https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates/releases, that will show you the proper way to register your javascript and styles.  But here is an example MVC view with the script registration:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement

@{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/DesktopModules/MVC/DotNetNuclear/RestaurantMenu/Resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/DesktopModules/MVC/DotNetNuclear/RestaurantMenu/Resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", 20);
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/DesktopModules/MVC/DotNetNuclear/RestaurantMenu/Resources/module.css");
}
```

I put this at the top of my .cshtml view above the html.

Comment: Yes i am using Chris Hammond's MVC module template only, Yes i have come accrose this option but if you can see in my question  ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript method but 1st argument is System.Web.UI.Page. what should i pass as this parameter? Dnn.DnnPage is not available for me in crish hammond's template.

Comment: Dnn.DnnPage does not exists, what do I need to reference?

Comment: @Arcadian - You should have reference to DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc